# Which models to use for high dimensional unsupervised classification?

Tags: clustering

I have some telemetry data from cars that record about 500 variables (eg. engine temp, exhaust temp...). I wanted to be able to classify the data according to the car's activities whether it be idling, climbing a hill, etc...

There is no target labels so I was thinking along the lines of performing clustering to explore the data and potential clusters. Since the data is high dimensional, I need something that is flexible.

I was wondering which models would be good for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to the community and secondly, BIG ALARM!

**Unsupervised** and **Classification** are two fundamentally different keywords in Machine Learning. As you asked for unsupervised classification, I strongly recommend to make yourself familiar with these concepts to avoid falling into *doing things without knowing its background* which may result in not so meaningful results.

Third, I assume two scenarios bellow and answer your question:

1. **You Have Those Labels** i.e. *climbing*, *idling*, etc. Then you have a classification problem and the classification itself has nothing to do with being unsupervised. You can use unsupervised algorithms for feature engineering but the classification itself is **supervised**. In this case you have options which are OK with high dimensional data e.g. SVMs, Random Forests and ANNs. Write the basic architecture (in Python, Sci-kit Learn gives you proper tools to start) and do cross-validation and monitor your model. At this step it is too broad to discuss it.
2. **You Do Not Have Those Labels** and you want to **cluster** data to different bunches of similar activities according to your variables. That is **Unsupervised** and yes, you can do that but you do not know out-of-the-box, which one is climbing and which one is idling at the beginning.
3. **In Case of 2**, you may cluster your data and check a few samples from each cluster and if you can manually label, label them according to different activities and assume the rest of cluster represents the same activities. Still your problem is **unsupervised** so soon or late you come to the question of *how many clusters should I assume in my data?* which is another issue.

### UPDATE

So the problem is he second case. This is the solution:

1. Firstly try EDA to understand your data. Dimensionality reduction is a good way to reduce the number of features to less but more informative one. I suggest starting with visualisation with UMAP or t-SNE and see how your data looks like (intuitively)
2. Try dimensionality reduction algorithms and intuitively see the data. It gives you a rough idea of which algorithm to use. I suggest simple PCA, kernel PCA, LLE and UMAP as mentioned before
3. Depending on the distribution of data and clusters you choose the proper algorithm. In case of well-separated gaussian clusters a simple k-means would do the job. DBSCAN is used when **density** of clusters are different. Spectral clustering is a computationally expensive but pretty nonlinear approach to clustering problem too
4. **Clustering has no evaluation** You need to manually check your clusters and see if they make sense. This is not to get rid of answering! this is a fact that I see being mistaken frequently. There is no evaluation for clustering except of manually label some data and see if they are in right cluster!

PS: KNN is a supervised algorithm and needs label. You mentioned in comments so I thought it is good to correct it here too.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help and the correction. The second case is what my problem is about.

In the case of clustering, what would be the most flexible model. I have tried KNN but it relies on convex cluster shapes and as I have many columns, it's unlikely that the clusters are convex. I am looking for a robust model that can fit different cluster shapes.

Also would you suggest dimension reduction at the start. I was thinking of doing PCA but since the data has high dimensionality and may not be well behaved, I am not sure if it is the best option.

Comment: I update the answer. "In case it helped" plz consider accepting it. We do it non-profit on our free time. Thanks :)